# Check User Tokens are valid or not using Twitter Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I have a Asp.Net application that will post tweets in twitter.
I'm using Twitterizer2 for doing this.

First time when the user uses the application, he will be redirected to twitter for authentication.
And then the user-token will be stored in my application , so that the user will never be asked again to login  to twitter.
This is working fine.

Now i want to validate the user-tokens before posting (ie valid token or not) . Is there any way to do this validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the code for validating tokens in another question.
The Twitterizer Api itself had the Methods to validate the User tokens.
The code is as follows:

```
Twitterizer.OAuthTokens token = new Twitterizer.OAuthTokens();
token.ConsumerKey = this.AppId;
token.ConsumerSecret = this.AppSecret;
token.AccessToken = userToken;
token.AccessTokenSecret = userSecret;

Twitterizer.TwitterResponse<Twitterizer.TwitterUser> response =
    Twitterizer.TwitterAccount.VerifyCredentials(token);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ErrorMessage))
{
    //This is a valid token
}
else
{
    //Invalid token
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a call to the [Verify Credentials API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/verify_credentials)

Make an authenticated call to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

It will respond with HTTP 200 OK if the tokens are correct - or 401 if they are not.

Comment: Thanks Terence. But how can i pass the usertoken (credentials) to the twitter for validation?

Comment: Use whichever library you're using to make the call to verify_credentials - that will tell you if everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

MoH's code didn't work for me. Here's what I did:

```
public bool IsTwitterAccessTokenValid(String access_token, String token_secret)
    {
        var token = new Twitterizer.OAuthTokens();
        token.ConsumerKey = this.TwitterConsumerKey;
        token.ConsumerSecret = this.TwitterConsumerSecret;
        token.AccessToken = access_token;
        token.AccessTokenSecret = token_secret;

        var twitterResponse = TwitterAccount.VerifyCredentials(token);

        return (twitterResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success);
    }
```

Comment: Almost the same code, Only difference is where you determined the success or failure from the response. Anyway thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: Yeah I copied yours and since it didn't work for me I modified it. Without your input it would be more troublesome for me. Thanks.